# Impact of book chapters

Tags: faculty-application, books, bibliometrics

In my PhD, i have 2 chapters published in book chapters published by springer and elsavir. To what extent do you think the importantance of book chapters regarding in the PhD student CV? Does these chapters have a good impact when applying for faculty positions ? 
Hint: i have other journal and conference papers.

Comment: Are these chapters open-access publications? if yes see https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/126686/93566; if no see https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/6133/93566

Comment: What is the point of the 'Hint'?

Comment: @JonCustet: As I understand, the hint gives us additional information.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider them important, but it would depend on the books in which they are contained and what your contribution is to the overall content. It could also indicate that you have a circle of collaborators already in place, which is a good thing for a new faculty member.

But, I'm not sure why you ask. Certainly they are something to include in your CV and they will be evaluated like everything else in your application materials.